# Bash script to enable mod_rewrite AllowOverride All

Tags: linux, apache, bash, mod-rewrite

I am moving away from AMPPS / MAMP and looking to build a dev environment as close to the production environment as possible.

As such, I am using Vagrant / VirtualBox on my Mac with CentOS 6.4 64bit os box installed.

In my vagrant file, I have a provisioning script:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
```

And at the moment, my bootstrap.sh looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install the remi repos
sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

# Update the repositories
sudo yum -y update

sudo yum -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

Now I have my apache server installed, I want my bash script to edit the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in my html directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

...

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

...

    # Need to change this to AllowOverride All via bash script
    AllowOverride None

...

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/645799/using-sed-to-enable-htaccess-files-in-apache-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice oneliner for you:

```
sed "$(grep -n "AllowOverride None" input.file |cut -f1 -d:)s/.*/AllowOverride All/" input.file > output.file
```

For the breakdown:

- `grep -n "AllowOverride None" input.file` returns the lines that match the pattern, preceeded by the line number
- `cut -f1 -d:` cuts the string and returns the first number it encounters
- `sed "$LINE_NUMBERs/.*/AllowOverride All/" input.file` puts "AllowOverride All" at the line n° `$LINE_NUMBER`

You then just have to redirect the output to the file you want.

Et voila !

Answer (score 15):

**Use Linux SED command to search & replace a line between two patterns**

Another nice solution is to use the SED command to search & replace a line between two patterns. In your case the patterns would be:

```
'<Directory "/var/www/html">' and </directory>'
```

This way you replace only the line 'AllowOverride None' inside your html directory `(<Directory "/var/www/html">)` and not every line that contains 'AllowOverride None' in your httpd.conf file.

The command SED supports patterns ranges in this form:

```
sed '/startpattern/,/endpattern/ <sed-commands>' file
```

In your case, this becomes:

```
sed -i '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride all/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

The -i option is used to edit files in place. If you don’t use the option -i, then the modified output will be printed on the screen and the file wouldn’t be modified!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I my case (apache 2.4) you don't need the quotes `sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
`